# Why doesn't Morse code try to achieve more compression?

Tags: information-theory

I was working on the [Morse code Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) , when I noticed something strange.

There might be a reason, but I can't find it.

As you can see, the code symbol `...-.` is not used, however the code symbol `-----` is. **Why?**

The first symbol is shorter (`11`) than the second one (`19`).

This is not the only code symbol unused.

Answer (score 10):

Three possible reasons:

1. `...-.` is used by a [prosign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosigns_for_Morse_code#Table_of_Morse_Prosigns) meaning *understood*;
2. using `-----` for the digit 0 makes the encoding of digits regular, thus easier to memorize;
3. `-----` for the digit 0 could be replaced by the shorter `---` for the letter O, in contexts where it is clear that a digit is thought.

I conjecture that 2 is the historical reason.

Comment: I have been CW (Morse Code) operator for many years (decades) and I have never heard the digit zero sent as the letter O.  But, alternatively, the digit zero is often sent as a long dash and I do this myself.  Hard to do with a paddle and keyer and because of that I have a straight key available at all times.  The digit 9 (----.) is also a long code and it is often sent as the letter N but usually only in a signal report of 5NN sent instead of 599.

Comment: @K7PEH: This question was recently bumped to the "front page" (an edit of vonbrand's answer) and after seeing your comment I thought I'd mention that [my father](https://www.qrz.com/db/K4OF) got his Extra class license in 1951 (age 16 or 17) and was a "high-speed coder", one of two or three dozen people in the world (at least in the late 1960s to early 1980s) who communicated 50-70 WPM (I think) in special a (some?) dedicated band location(s). I never, ever recall him writing anything down. **(continued)**

Comment: Often when he was finished sending (using a special device that you touch left-and-right, not an up-and-down key) he'd go get something from the kitchen, listening to the code as one would listen to someone talk (sound always turned up a bit high for my taste). Many times when doing this he'd talk to my mother, something like: "I'm talking to Carl in New Mexico now. Oh, just now he said that his dog recently died and . . . Oh, now he wants to know how you're doing. What should I tell him?" Being so saturated with this growing up, I stayed away from anything electronics **(continued)**

Comment: (which probably also has to do with my neglect of computers -- took a PL-1 programming class in 1977, nothing since to the determinant to my financial situation as pure math doesn't really get you anywhere except teaching unless you're **really, really** good at it), but my 2-years younger brother is a ham and does electronics repair work, mostly cell-phone towers stuff I think.

Answer (score 4):

Morse code was defined by Morse himself, and later (somewhat) extended. Using letter frequency for dense coding was a consideration (`.` for the commonest letter `e`, and on down), trying to make it easy to learn clearly was a goal, and (some) resistance to garbling; but all this happened long before Shannon's study of communication or any systematic study of coding, error detection and such.